# Historical cost of semiconductor fab

Tags: history, chip

How much did a state-of-the-art semiconductor foundry cost in or around 1980?

Ideally I'd like to get data on how it changed over time from the seventies to present day, but even a single data point from around that time would be good to have.

Comment: That question is certainly too broad as it stands. You could build simple semiconductors (say, Germanium diodes) in a backyard shop with your friend from 3rd-party-sourced raw material, or you could be Fairchild Semiconductor, employing more than 5000 people - Both would be "state of the art". "Fab" is too broad in itself as well: *fabricating* semiconductors can be relatively easy, once you know how to do it and once you have engineered all the machines to produce them - so 90% of the process is research and engineering, not fabricating. Would you in- or exclude that?

Comment: Rummage around the CHM oral history archives if interested in such gritty details. See you for black coffee in a few months.... :)

Comment: Here's some analysis of fabrication cost trends from 1980 to 1995: http://smithsonianchips.si.edu/ice/cd/CEICM/SECTION2.pdf

Comment: Um, I don't agree with this being closed. Capital cost of building a new fab for any major semiconductor company would be a realistic answer.